# BlocBuilder's build method is not invoked when adding an event to this bloc from inside another bloc

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, lazy-evaluation, flutter-bloc, injectable

I have `bloc A`, created and provided above all the widgets of my app.

I have `Bloc B`, created and provided in `screen 1`.

`Bloc B` has a reference to `Bloc A` and can add events to `Bloc A` inside `mapEventToState` of `Bloc B`.

Now the weird thing:

Inside screen 1, I have a `BlocBuilder` of `Bloc A`,

If I add events directly ( `blocAReference.add(blockAEvent)` the `BlocBuilder` gets called when the state changes),

However when I add an event indirectly to `Bloc A` (`blocBrefrence.add(blockBEvent)` and then inside `mapEventToState` of `Bloc B` I add event to `Bloc A`), then the `BlocBuilder` is not invoked (but I can assure by `print`ing to console that the event was added to `Bloc A`)

I am using the `flutter_bloc` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

The logic is all good except for one thing, I am using `injectable` library to manage dependencies,

and I was annotating my `Bloc A` as `@Injectable()`,

so when the library wants to inject `Bloc A` into `Bloc B`'s constructor,

it was creating a new instance of `Bloc A` every time and that instance was different from the one I was listening to in the `BlocBuilder` (the one I am listening to is the one provided on top of the widget tree, I am looking it up using `context.bloc<BlocA>()`
)

So there are 2 solutions:

1. I keep the `@Injectable()` annotation on `Bloc A` but now I don't inject `Bloc A` into `Bloc B` but rather I send the instance of `Bloc A` with every event added to `Bloc B` (i.e. as a function parameter)
2. I remove `@Injectable()` annotation from `Bloc A` and replace it with `@LazySingleton` so that all lookups using `context.bloc<BlocA>()` will make `injectable` library give me the same instance of the `Bloc A` which I created above all my widgets